# Refresh MS SQL database

Tags: sql-server, restore, sqlcmd

I'm doing a refresh of a microsoft sql database with the following command line :

```
sqlcmd  -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [db] FROM DISK = 'D:\backup.bak'"
```

But the restore crashes the old database but I want to keep certain users and logins from the previous database.
How can I do it ? 
Thanks

Comment: Your question makes little sense. What do you mean it "crashes" the database? If the current database contains things that aren't in your backup (like users -- not logins, because those are server-level) you'll need to script those first and reapply them.

Comment: `RESTORE` is a physical operation that replaces the target database files from the source backup so the restored database is exactly like the source backup, including database-scoped objects like database users. Instance-level objects like logins must be handled separately as @JeroenMostert mentioned. `RESTORE` is an offline operation that requires exclusive access to the target database so you can't use the db during the restore operation.

Comment: thank you guys, actually my problem is that the backup contains a login with the same name as the current login except each one was attached to a user that also has the same name but with different passwords! should I then remove the login after each restore and just recreate it ?